# How to compare the user input values in a default list?

Tags: bash, shell

In my script, there are some default values in a list. I want to compare the user input values that are stored in the list to a default list. If any of the two values are present in the 4 values of the table then the `if` condition should return true.

My code is like:

```
#!/bin/bash
list1="paras virat hardik rohit"
read -p "input two players" one two
list2="$one $two"
if [ "$list2" == "list1" ]
then
    echo "Two players selected"
else
    echo "none are selected"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest writing a helper function that checks if a single player is listed. Then you can run the function twice to check each of the two players entered.

You may notice I've changed the strings to arrays. Arrays are better at holding multiple values since they allow values to contain whitespace and are easier to index and iterate over.

```
is_player_listed() {
    local player="$1"
    local players=(paras virat hardik rohit)

    for p in "${players[@]}"; do
        [[ "$p" == "$player" ]] && return 0
    fi
    return 1
}

read -p "input two players" one two

if is_player_listed "$one" || is_player_listed "$two"; then
    echo "Two players selected"
else
    echo "None are selected"
fi
```

You could even extract a generic `contains` function to check if an array contains a value, since there's no built-in way to do such a check.

```
contains() {
    local target="$1"
    shift
    local values=("$@")

    for value in "${values[@]}"; do
        [[ "$value" == "$target" ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}

is_player_listed() {
    local player="$1"
    local players=(paras virat hardik rohit)

    contains "$player" "${players[@]}"
}
```